# Display Number of Iterations in Output Window

Tags: python, list, iteration

In python, a massive list that I'm trying to sort is taking a long time (~15 seconds) to sort.

I'm wondering if there is any way to indicate to the user, the number of elements sorted in real time, without having to print out a new line for each completed iteration.

So instead of having:

```
2300 elements sorted
2301 elements sorted
...
```

There'd just be a single line:

```
x+ elements sorted
```

I apologize in advance if I messed up the terminology.
And thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: The Sorting Algorithm

```
def insertionSort(allData, key):
    for i in range(1, len(allData)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and allData[j][key] < allData[j-1][key]:
            allData[j], allData[j-1] = allData[j-1], allData[j]
            j -= 1
```

Comment: are you performing the sort with `sorted(list)` or `list.sort()` or some custom sorting technique? Because the former don't really expose their internal "iterations"

Comment: Perhaps should have specified, I'm using my own sorting algorithm

Comment: If you can post your algorithm, please do so

Comment: Perhaps I don't follow, but your suggestion would still seem to result in thousands of printed statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the print function from python 3. Replace the line ending, which is '\n' on Unix or "\r\n" on Windows, with '\r', **carriage return**. This moves the cursor to the left side of the screen but keeps it on the same line.

```
import os

x = 1000000

print( "Sorting List:" )
for i in range( 0, x ):
    print( str( i ) + "/" + str( x ) + " elements sorted", end='\r' )
```

---

For python 2.x you can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to get the new print function

---

In GNOME Terminal the cursor flickers around when printing, I thought this was distracting so I turned it off with

```
os.system('setterm -cursor off')
```

and back on again with

```
os.system('setterm -cursor on')
```

This may vary from system to system